# How to fill missing values from other variable?

Tags: r, dataset

My data set is composed as below.

```
x    y 
0     
0    0
2    2
     2
     4
2
7    7
```

I want to merge x and y variable like this

```
x  
0     
0  
2  
2
4
2
7
```

That is, I want to fill x variable values with y variable values if x are missing. If there is no missing in both x and y variables two values are always same.

Comment: are blank `''` or `NA`? If `''` it means your column containing figures are effectively of character type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another variant

```
x = ifelse(is.na(x), y,x)
```

Comment: Really elegant answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just copy the `y` values for for the missing `x` values

```
x <- c(0,0,2,NA,NA,2,7)
y <- c(NA,0,2,2,4,NA,7)

x[is.na(x)] <- y[is.na(x)]
```

Comment: If the missing is not NA, How should I do that?

Comment: Well, what's "missing"? If it's not NA, then do what ever the appropriate test is for the indexing.

Comment: do this `gsub("\\s", NA, dataset)` before MrFlick's answer and check

Comment: mode(x[blank observation number]) shows "numeric", class(x[blank observation number]) is factor and is.na(class(x[blank observation number])) shows "FALSE"

Comment: Solved by using ifelse.

Answer (score 2):

As your data is already in a `data.frame` it seems:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(0,0,2,NA,NA,2,7), y = c(NA,0,2,2,4,NA,7))
```

Then simply get the larger value from the columns:

```
> apply(df, 1, max, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 0 0 2 2 4 2 7
```

Answer (score 2):

If like you say that both of `x` and `y` are the same when there are no missing values, you can easily vectorize with `rowMeans` or use `pmax` (or `pmin`) combined with `do.call`

**Your data**

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(0,0,2,NA,NA,2,7), y = c(NA,0,2,2,4,NA,7))
```

**Solution #1**

```
rowMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)
## [1] 0 0 2 2 4 2 7
```

**Solution #2**

```
do.call(pmax, c(df, na.rm = TRUE)) # or do.call(pmin, c(df, na.rm = TRUE))
## [1] 0 0 2 2 4 2 7
```

---

For comparison, this will lose only to @MrFlicks approach on a relatively big data

```
n <- 1e5
dftest <- data.frame(x = as.vector(replicate(n, df$x)),
                     y = as.vector(replicate(n, df$y)))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(ifelse(is.na(dftest$x), dftest$y, dftest$x),
               dftest$x[is.na(dftest$x)] <- dftest$y[is.na(dftest$x)],
               apply(dftest, 1, max, na.rm = TRUE),
               rowMeans(dftest, na.rm = TRUE),
               do.call(pmax, c(dftest, na.rm = TRUE)))

# Unit: milliseconds
#                                                   expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
#            ifelse(is.na(dftest$x), dftest$y, dftest$x)  121.16554  132.17962  188.81260  162.88925  242.37786  452.3506   100
# dftest$x[is.na(dftest$x)] <- dftest$y[is.na(dftest$x)]   32.46432   34.13887   45.88664   36.78413   42.72560  138.9821   100
#                    apply(dftest, 1, max, na.rm = TRUE) 2284.13414 2428.15899 2554.03813 2501.33842 2605.78132 3567.5111   100
#                         rowMeans(dftest, na.rm = TRUE)   40.04718   44.39996   61.89289   48.16691   54.88427  189.2017   100
#                 do.call(pmax, c(dftest, na.rm = TRUE))   44.68004   45.66772   52.64246   46.43867   50.02424  149.1624   100
```